# Jquery - Displaying the value selected from datepicker into another textbox

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to get values selected from textboxes and displaying them in a  different textbox on a summary page (all designed on the same page). For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<label for="txt-outbound-date" class="left p-input-label" >Date: </label>
<input type="text" id="txt-outbound-date" name="txt-outbound-date" class="input-txt-sml left required" />
```

Summary page HTML:

```
<div class="div-contact-label-wrap">
    <label for="txt-selected-date" class="right p-input-label" >Outbound Date: </label>
</div>
<div class="div-contact-input-wrap">
    <input type="text" id="txt-selected-date" name="txt-selected-date" class="input-txt-sml left" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$('#txt-outbound-date').change(function() {
    $('#txt-selected-date').val($(this).val());
});
```

This works perfectly okay for every textbox I have except for the 'Selected Date' textbox which uses Jquery datepicker to get the selected value. When I select a value and get to the summary page, no value is copied across. If I go back to the previous page and select a different date, the date that was previously selected will be displayed in the textbox.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

I've also tried:

```
$('#txt-outbound-date').click(function() {
   $('#txt-selected-date').val($(this).val());
});
```

But that didn't work either. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepicker-event `onSelect`:

```
$('#txt-outbound-date').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $('#txt-selected-date').val(dateText);
   }
});
```

Comment: If it's not working, why did you accept it as an answer? What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Very strange. http://jsfiddle.net/G89dN/ - seems to be working. 1) Did you remove your `change` event handler, described in question? 2) Did you add `onSelect` to your initialization of datepicker or just insert the code from answer?

Comment: It did work, the problem on that the date picker already had an onSelect function which I didn't realise as I was taking over from somebody elses code. I simply added the function to the exsisting one and it works, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

this solution (datepicker-event onSelect) doesn't work for this type of datepicker

```
  params.datepicker = {
  selector: '#startdate, #enddate, minDate:'<%=date()%>'
  }
```

This solution here only works if you type in the textbox or put your cursor in the textbox after clicking on the datepicker image icon

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#startdate').click(function() {
            var inputValues = [];
            $("#startdate").each(function() {
                inputValues.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#enddate').each(function(index) {
                if(index < inputValues.length) {
                    $(this).val(inputValues[index]);
                }
            });
        });
 });
```

and this solution works well with html5/bootstraps (but I am looking for an old solution with wet2 templates with an older version of a datepicker)

```
$('#startdate').change(function(){
    $('#enddate').val($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the original question. If you have a question then please post it as a new question.